# NPM install showing multiple errors in windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm

```
PS C:\Users\debro\Documents\Razor> npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\debro\Documents\Razor/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\debro\Documents\Razor\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\debro\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-07T07_14_27_750Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\debro\Documents\Razor>
```

I installed Node. ran npm --version it showed result and also added npm and node in system environemnt variables

[image]

but still can't run npm install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have `package.json` file ?

```
no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\debro\Documents\Razor\package.json'
```

Comment: You can use the `npm init -y` command to create a `package.json` file in your project directory